# I am tracking packages on Pitney Bowes site I can't get the search button be enabled using excel VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I am trying to track packages on Pitney Bowes web site but can't seem to get the search button to not be disabled when I enter a tracking number.  I have tried send Sending and Chr(13) to simulate enter key doesn't work please help I believe it is because it is a JScript page. There are a few line of code I tried which did not work they are commented out.
My code:

```
Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
Set HTMLInputs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("textarea")
'Set HTMLtags = HTMLDoc.getElementsById("search-box")
For Each HTMLInput In HTMLInputs
    If HTMLInput.innerText = "Enter up to 50 tracking numbers (one per line, no commas)" Then
        HTMLInput.Value = TNs(x, 1)
    End If
'Debug.Print HTMLInput.Name, HTMLInput.tagName, HTMLInput.ID, HTMLInput.innerText
Next HTMLInput

Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
If HTMLButtons(0).getAttribute("class") = "css-djgcds e1lr09737" Then
    HTMLButtons(0).disabled = False
    'HTMLDoc.querySelector("input[type='button']").removeAttribute ("disabled")
    'iebtn = Set HTMLButtons(0).getAttribute("class") = "css-1aw3qyu e1lr09737"
    
End If
HTMLButtons(0).Click
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
```

'elements of web Page:

```
<textarea style="height: 49px;" placeholder="Enter up to 50 tracking numbers (one per line, no _ 
 commas)" data-test-id="search-box-input" data-gtm-id="search-box">92612927005592000013632330                   
</textarea>
<button class="css-djgcds e1lr09737" data-test-id="search-box-button" data-gtm-id="search-box-icon"> 
<i class="css-aw5xkv e1u4d0xr0"></i></button>
```

Comment: What's the url? I don't see that problem here for example: https://parceltracker.pb.com/

Comment: Sorry that part of the code got cut off    IE.navigate "https://pitneybowes.shipment.co/track"

Comment: Is shipment different or can you use the url I show?

Comment: I tried the URL you have and I can click on the "track" button but when the code clicks it the page responds with "no package with that tracking number found". but they are found when not using the code.  very frustrating.

Comment: you mean manually works? It is probably that you need to trigger an event

Comment: the post form event?

Comment: I tried    " IE.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).submit " and it put the tracking number in the URL but did give me the page???  Thanks so much for your help BTW

Comment: do I need to trigger a JAVA event?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=event+listeners+user%3A6241235+is%3Aanswer